# Disconnect LAN cable using command line?

Tags: macos, network

## TL;DR:

> I need to run `ifconfig <iface> ether <mac>`, but this cannot run if the network cable is connected. The interface has no IP before the ether command, even with connected cable.
>
> So, either I need to be able to dected a connected LAN cable and block the operation until the cable is unplugged, or I need to be able to "virtually unplug" the cable and then run the command.

## Long edition:

I'm wondering if there's a command to make Mac think that the LAN cable is disconnected without bringing the interface down and without physically unplugging the cable?

I want to run the `ether` command, but this doesn't work with the interface down. The problem is that our switch is configured to automatically block ports where more than one MAC address is active on a port (to block the chance that someone plugs in a hub/switch, over which I have no control).

But to be able to run the `ether` command, the device cannot be down so it needs to be disconnected.

I know I can physically disconnect the cable, but I want to be sure that I don't accidentally run the script. The procedure to get the port unlocked takes pretty long.

(Alternative could be to detect the cable connection status, if that is possible from the CLI, and refuse to continue)

Comment: Can‘t you just ping a remote host from your script and stop it it works?

Comment: No there is no IP at that point yet (it's a complex situation, sorry). The interface only gets an IP after the new mac address. And thanks Nimesh for the edit, I assumed it was a macos exhange but of course it's apple.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you add some more details about the steps you need to do, and when exactly the cable needs to be virtually unplugged.

Comment: Not much more information than what I gave but added the tl;dr.